# Compilation fails due to strange characters appearing in source code

Tags: c, gcc, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to write a simply [Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) program, but when attempting to compile with GCC, I receive the following error:

```
helloworld.c:5:18: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘World’
  printf(“Hello World”);
                  ^
helloworld.c:5:18: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
helloworld.c:5:18: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
helloworld.c:5:18: error: stray ‘\235’ in program
```

Why is this?

Compiler: [GCC 4.8.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) (2014-12-19). OS: [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr).

Comment: If your source really has curly quotes around `“Hello World”`, C can't understand them. Use typewriter-style straight quotes, ASCII code 34: `"Hello World"`. If your editor converts pairs of straight quotes to curly quotes, turn that option off.

Comment: you will find `geany`  and `gedit` to be MUCH better for editing code than using a word processor like `libre` .  (and in geany, you can set the compile and build menu items to use gcc with all the desirable parameters, so you only have to enter it once and it will be good 'forever'

Comment: Direct analysis: 342 200 235 (octal)   → 0xE2 0x80 0x9D (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+201D ([RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9)).

Comment: There is probably also an error triplet for the other quote: \342 \200 \234 (U+201C ([LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.charset.org/utf-8/9))). It must have been the first error. Why was it left out?

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The octal sequence 342 200 234 is the UTF-8 byte sequence for the  [typographic double quote](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/%7Erichard/utf-8.cgi?input=342+200+235&mode=obytes).

To fix it, replace it with the regular double quote, i.e. `"` instead of `“`.

Answer (score 5):

```
printf(“Hello World”);
```

This should be written as -

```
printf("Hello World");
```

Straight quotes should be used. Try changing style .

Comment: Why do you mean by *"changing style"*? Changing encoding will probably not remove the offending characters.